# Artificial Intelligence Synaptic Connection strength simulation

Tags: java, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to create an AI based on the idea of Neurons and Synaptic Connections. This is similar to a Neural Network but different in the sense that it does not use a trial and error like system such as back propagation. I want the AI to form connections between Neurons and then each time the connection is traveled down, it grows in size making it easier for the next time it is fired.

As I understand from researching this, this is how the human mind works. A Neuron fires a connection to another Neuron and that connection grows. This is how habits and addictions form. The paths eventually get so large in size that the firing of that connection becomes almost automatic.

The problem is, the only way I can think of this is with a number. I have an double that represents the size of the Synaptic Connection. Each time the connection is fired, the number increases. I would then just sort the list of connections by the size of the connection.

However, this only solves the problem of priority. It allows the AI to choose which Neuron to go to but I'm struggling in how to make the connection faster or slower based on that number.

I want the AI to be able to have the ability of having trouble recalling information. Yes I know this sounds like a strange thing to want but the goal of this project is to have behavior as close to a human as possible... and we definitely have trouble recalling information at times.

This means that, at times, the AI should have to think about something for a minute before figuring something out. It shouldn't be able to fire in the same amount of time as every single other connection.

My current implementation of a Synaptic Connection is in this class: https://github.com/ianbro/Adamation/blob/master/src/com/ianmann/mind/NeuralPathway.java.

Please let me know if you have any ideas how to implement the difference in speed of Synaptic Connection firing.

---- Update ----

Lets say I ask him what his favorite ice cream flavor is. For me, I don't really have one so I might have to think about it for a while. But if I just had a simple input => output system, then the AI would just grab the highest connection between an icecream flavor and the idea of liking something. But if that number is low, then that might mean he doesn't necessarily have a favorite, like in my case. So he would have to think about it because the connection to be fired that contains the answer is not found easily.

Comment: The analogy to human learning is somebody telling you "yes, that's the right answer" so the neural path that lead to the correct answer is strengthened. 
 Conversely, somebody telling you "no, that's not the right answer" diminishes the neural path which lead to the incorrect answer.  What will be the feedback mechanism for the system to learn?  The answer might suggest how to model the system.

Comment: Well... the thing is... I'm not necessarily looking for the AI to do exactly what I want. The idea is that the AI understands what we are saying and responds in a logical way (if it even wants to respond at all). So the connections are not simply "input => output". They are also used for structure of sentences. So it will store the knowledge of a person as a group of organized neurons. There's not correct or incorrect input and output here... it's just a network of knowledge.

...

Comment: Lets say I ask him what his favorite ice cream flavor is.

For me, I don't really have one so I might have to think about it for a while. But if I just had a simple input => output system, then the AI would just grab the highest connection between an icecream flavor and the idea of liking something. But if that number is low, then that might mean he doesn't necessarily have a favorite, like in my case. So he would have to think about it because the connection to be fired that contains the answer is not found easily.

Comment: And also, it's not that yes or no determines connection size. Because the idea of correctness will also be stored as neurons... so how can a neuron be used to determine itself. Instead, We use multiple paths of logic. The neuron will have to decide if it wants to choose the correct answer in the first place or not (like in the case of sarcasm or lying).

Comment: Instead, connection size is determined by the usage of that pathway. This is why things like drug addiction forms... It's can be considered an incorrect output but simply because the person chose that option so many times in the past, the pathway is so large that it forms a habit... and then the reliance on that path being taken leads to discomfort when it's not taken. It does this even though it's not considered "correct". Yes I know addictions is a little more complicated than this but that's the general idea of how they form.

Comment: Sorry I know that's a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I grasp what you are trying to do here, but no matter! The obvious (to me) way to speed or slow a connection is to place intermediate steps. Each step is associated with a delay (simply the extra time to compute bridging the connection in a simple model). To speed the connection remove the intermediate steps and so on...

Comment: That actually might just be it. Its an inverse comparison (smaller number = faster connection instead of large = fast) but it will allow the quicker ones to fire before other weaker connection which will solve the problem of priority too. Thanks!